# Phonegap backbutton event, detect first page in history?

Tags: javascript, cordova

Adding a `backbutton` event listener to my Phonegap 2.0 mobile app prevents the user from exiting using the back key.

Before adding the event listener this was working: if the user visited N pages and clicked back N+1 times, the app would close (or go in the background for android 4.0 or higher).

Please see my code bellow.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){
    if (window.history.length == 0) { // this does not work
        function quitApp(){
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
        navigator.notification.confirm(
            "Are you sure you want to quit?",
            quitApp,
            'App Title',
            'Cancel,Ok');
        return;
    }
    if (typeof(window.activePage.onBack) === 'function') {
        window.activePage.onBack();
    } else {
        window.history.back();          
    }
}, false);
```

Any idea how i can achieve this: allow the user to exit using the back button while keeping my event listener?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind the back button on your title page, maybe something like this:

```
$('#home-page-title').bind( 'pageinit',function(event){

      document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){
           navigator.app.exitApp();
  }, false);

});
```